# Successfully installed numpy and pandas, but cannot call pandas in Python Shell

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, pip

I am using Python 2.7.12 on a Windows 7 machine

I need to run a .py script that calls `arcpy`, `numpy` and `pandas`.

I have not been able to import `arcpy` using Anaconda, so I deleted Anaconda from my machine and am trying to import `pandas` and `numpy` using the python shell.

I figured out how to use `pip` to install `numpy` and `pandas` using the command prompt.

[image: command prompt output]

All looks good, right? When I attempt to import `numpy` and `pandas` into python using the Python shell, I am able to import `numpy`, but I get an error when I try to import `pandas`.

[image: Python shell error message]

Any idea why I get the error message when I try to import `pandas` but not when I import `numpy`?

What I have tried so far:

I did try updating `pip`, which unfortunately did not solve the problem.

I also tried manually downloading the .whl file from pypi.python.org and calling that file using `pip`. Again, the command prompt output tells me pandas is installed, but when I run the `import pandas` command in the Python Shell, I still get an error.

I have also tried restarting my machine...multiple times :-/

Any ideas on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly an issue with your PYTHONPATH, but it's difficult to tell. You can view your PYTHONPATH by entering `echo %PYTHONPATH%` in command prompt / powershell. There is some documentation on the Python website that might be helpful diagnose the problem: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

I don't use Windows anymore, but when I did I found the easiest way to get everything working was to use the Anaconda Python distribution (https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/). The installer does all the environment configuration for you and I found `conda` more reliable than `pip` on Windows.

This (blog post)[https://pymorton.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/using-arcpy-with-anaconda/] suggests you might have had a problem using ArcPY because ArcGIS adds it's own Python install. This answer on gis.stackexchange.com might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/how-to-get-arcpy-to-work-with-anaconda

Comment: How could I check to see if it is an issue with PYTHONPATH? Anaconda does not come with Arcpy though, so I have to deal with a similar issue getting Anaconda to load arcpy. As you mentioned, that may be easier to fix than the issue I am currently having. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You were exactly right about the PYHONPATH being wrong. Since I have ArcGIS installed on my machine, the PYTHONPATH was referencing an ArcGIS folder, NOT the folder where the pandas files were being saved when I ran the pip install command.

The numpy command worked because those files coincidentally were **already** saved in the ArcGIS python folder. I guess the numpy package comes with ArcGIS. Who knew!

To fix my probelm, I copy and pasted the Pandas files from the default download location (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages) to the ArcGIS folder (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages).

For some reason, I actually had to replace the existing numpy files that were already installed in the ArcGIS folder with the new files I downloaded using the command prompt steps. The pandas files are linked with a specific version of the numpy files. So basically, I copy and pasted everything from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages into C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages and that fixed the problem. Yay!

I'm sure I could have updated the PYTHONPATH information with the default download location, but copy and pasting were easiest for me :-)

Solution! Thank you for your help! I never would have guessed the PYTONPATH was incorrect. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am using the regular Python. I had the same issue of not being able to import pandas even though I installed it along with numpy. It works in the script but not on the command line

I solved it by following these steps

1. Added the environment variable PYTHONPATH as  `C:\Python\Python36;C:\Python\Python36\Scripts`
2. Import numpy before you import pandas

```
import panda as pd
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "", line 1, in 
        import panda as pd
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\panda\__init__.py", line 1, in 
        from request import PandaRequest
    ImportError: cannot import name 'PandaRequest'
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```